# Dejar celdas vacias en una tabla HTML

Tags: php, mysql

¿Como puedo dejar celdas vacías de una tabla si en ese campo no quiero que aparezca nada? Estoy mandando a llamar unos nombres de unas materias registradas en mi base de datos, las mando a llamar y me las trae ahí no hay problema, el problema es cuando en una celda si no cumple la condición que le estoy diciendo que deje el campo en blanco y se ponga en el campo correspondiente, EJEMPLO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo Lunes se supone que tiene que estar en blanco, ya que en ese horario no hay clase, y el campo Miercoles tambien tiene que estar en blanco, mas no se acomodan

Dejo aqui el codigo:

```
<body>
    <?php require 'views/navbar.php'; ?>

    <div class="contenedor">
        <h2>Horario de clases</h2>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>HORA</th>
                    <th>LUNES</th>
                    <th>MARTES</th>
                    <th>MIERCOLES</th>
                    <th>JUEVES</th>
                    <th>VIERNES</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
                <?php foreach($datos = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM horario WHERE hora = 8') as $dato){ ?>
                <td><?php if(empty($dato)){
                    echo "Disponible";
                }else{
                    echo $dato ['materia'];
                } ?>
                </td>

                <?php } ?>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9:00 - 10:00</td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10:00 - 11:00</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11:00 - 12:00</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12:00 - 13:00</td>

            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
```

Alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer? Gracias

Campos de mi tabla horario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me manda esto de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para poder darte una respuesta concreta sería necesario conocer los campos de la tabla horario.

Comment: Los acabo de agregar

Comment: Una cosa más ¿Cuál es el formato de los días en el campo dia? L, M, X; Lun, Mar, Mie; Mon, Tue...

Comment: Es Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes

Comment: He colocado una nueva imagen de mis campos de la tabla horario

Comment: He añadido la respuesta con el resultado que muestra. Bastaría cambiar los datos simulados por la consulta que necesites.

Comment: Ha funcionado, te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema básicamente es que necesitas los días para ubicar cada materia.

Esto se puede hacer de muchas formas, una de las que propongo es usar los días para limitar el número de elementos que se imprimen por cada fila.

Después, comparar el día correspondiente con el día existente en el *array* que retorna la consulta.

> Lo he creado con datos simulados.

Quedaría así:

```
<?php
$dias=[
    'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes',
];
//$query=[
//    ['materia'=>'Arquitectura de computadoras', 'dia' => 'Martes'],
//    ['materia'=>'Modelos de Pronosticos', 'dia' => 'Jueves'],
//    ['materia'=>'Modelos de Pronosticos', 'dia' => 'Viernes'],
//];
$query  = $conexion->query('SELECT materia, dia FROM horario WHERE hora = 8');
$result = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>HORA</th>
        <th>LUNES</th>
        <th>MARTES</th>
        <th>MIERCOLES</th>
        <th>JUEVES</th>
        <th>VIERNES</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
        <?php foreach($dias as $dia) {
            $key = array_search($dia, array_column($result, 'dia'));
            if(false !== $key) {
                echo "<td>{$result[$key]['materia']}</td>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<td>Disponible</td>";
            }
        } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9:00 - 10:00</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /... -->
</table>
```

Esta es la salida:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>HORA</th>
        <th>LUNES</th>
        <th>MARTES</th>
        <th>MIERCOLES</th>
        <th>JUEVES</th>
        <th>VIERNES</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
        <td>Disponible</td>
        <td>Arquitectura de computadoras</td>
        <td>Disponible</td>
        <td>Modelos de Pronosticos</td>
        <td>Modelos de Pronosticos</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9:00 - 10:00</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /... -->
</table>
```

Comment: Funciono, más sin embargo como cambiaria los datos simulados por las consultas que necesito?

Comment: @EmanuelMejia la variable `$query`que hay al inicio, contiene el resultado de la consulta. Si `$conexion->query(...)` retorna el array, solo debes asignar ese resultado. Te lo cambio en la respuesta.

Comment: Me ha arrojado 2  warning y un error

Comment: @EmanuelMejia, ¿que retorna `$conexion->query(...)`? Para que funcione, la variable `$query` debe tener un array similar al que aparece comentado. Por como tenías montado el código, he supuesto que retorna un array similar al que pongo.

Comment: he añadido una foto con los errores que marca

Comment: @EmanuelMejia, He añadido la variable `$result`que obtiene el array. En el código se cambia `$query` por `$result`. Esto debería solucionar los _warning_.

Answer (score 1):

He realizado algo similar antes, lo ideal sería que crees una función para obtener el día y la hora según se requiera pero mientras prueba esto a ver si es lo que buscas.

```
<tr>
    <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
    <?php
    //Obtienes el resultado del Lunes a las 8
    $dato = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM horario WHERE hora = 8 AND dia = 'Lunes'");
    if($dato!=null){ ?>
    <td><?php echo $dato['materia']; ?></td>
    <?php } 
    else{ ?>
    <td>Disponible</td>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
    //Obtienes el resultado del Martes a las 8
    $dato = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM horario WHERE hora = 8 AND dia = 'Martes'");
    if($dato!=null){ ?>
    <td><?php echo $dato['materia']; ?></td>
    <?php } 
    else{ ?>
    <td>Disponible</td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

Espero dejarme entender pero lo que tienes que hacer es: en cada "tr" de hora debes recorrer cada día hasta el viernes. Según la celda en que te encuentres realizar una query de consultas. Este código se puede optimizar por ejemplo creando un método que enviando la hora y el día te devuelva el valor, pero la idea central se expresa bastante bien me parece.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que estoy viendo es que no reinicias la variable "$dato" con cada loop y por eso, a lo mejor, te pasa eso. Yo lo que haría sería lo siguiente:

```
<body>
<?php require 'views/navbar.php'; ?>

<div class="contenedor">
    <h2>Horario de clases</h2>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>HORA</th>
                <th>LUNES</th>
                <th>MARTES</th>
                <th>MIERCOLES</th>
                <th>JUEVES</th>
                <th>VIERNES</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>8:00 - 9:00</td>
            <?php foreach($datos = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM horario WHERE hora = 8') as $dato){ 
            ?>
            <td><?php if(empty($dato)){
                echo "Disponible";
            }else{
                echo $dato ['materia'];
            } 
            $dato = NULL; //Establece valor NULO a la variable?>
            </td>

            <?php } ?>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9:00 - 10:00</td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10:00 - 11:00</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11:00 - 12:00</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12:00 - 13:00</td>

        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

También puedes utilizar el comando "unset()" (ej. "unset($dato);") de PHP para destruir la variable y que la vuelva a crear posteriormente.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero me sigue saliendo igual, lo intente de las dos formas que me dijiste

Comment: Lo que busca tiene poco que ver con la respuesta. No es necesario reiniciar la variable y no tiene ningún control sobre el día en el que se inserta la materia.